# Git ignores my changes after revert action

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

Guys I have the following scenario:

1. I created a pull request with changes A,B,C (test-branch).
2. I merged this branch to development (test-branch => development).
3. I had to revert this merge;
4. I merged new things from other branches;

Now I want to merge again these changes from (test-branch) but I can't, always the I give `rebase` or `pull from test-brach` the changes are not coming..

I already did `reset hard origin/development` locally but does not work.

someone can help ? I think I have to delete from tree, but I don't know

Comment: This is either a dup or pretty close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68911641/184546). Either way, I believe the answer to that question will work for you.

Answer (score 5):

> Now I want to merge again these changes from (test-branch) but I can't

That's correct. After a merge, you cannot merge the same commits again; they are already merged.

The fact that the merge commit was subsequently reverted makes no difference. The revert commit undoes the *effects* of the merge commit, yes; but the merge commit itself, along with the accompanying topology, is still there.

For a complete discussion along with possible options, see the canonical https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt.

Comment: Hii @matt, thanks for answering...

you said: "After a merge, you cannot merge the same commits again; they are already merged.", even the changes cannot be merged again? I'm trying to pull changes directly from the commit of PR that I merged (before revert) but nothing happens.

Comment: "I'm trying to pull changes directly from the commit of PR that I merged" And that is _exactly_ what I've explained you cannot do. Please read my answer and the attached link.

Comment: Also stop using the word "changes". Git is about _commits_, not "changes."